# What is the origin of エンターティナー

Tags: loanwords

Some people use the word `エンターティナー` to mean 'entertainer'. I suspect this word comes from the English word `entertainer`. But the accented vowel is "ei", rather than "i". It would be a better approximation to transcribe it as `エンターテイナー`. Although the latter form is used, the former one is also used. How did `ティ` arise in place of `テイ`?

I had once thought of a possibility of hypercorrection, but am not sure.

Comment: I think that it is a perfect example of hypercorrection arising from words such as フイルム.  Is there an evidence it is not?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto If you say so, then it becomes more likely. I don't have evidence either for or against it. You brought a good example that triggered this kind of hypercorrection.

Comment: I realized that in some context, little ぃ is used as something like “weak い” instead of modifying the preceding vowel to い.  For example, there is a cake product named [かすてぃら](http://www.oohara.co.jp/kasutera.html) which is pronounced as かすていら, and some people write “へぃ” for Edo-dialect “へい” (searching [“へぃお待ち”](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%B8%E3%81%83%E3%81%8A%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1%22) shows 213 results).  So I wonder if those who write エンターティナー pronounce the word with テイ sound or really with ティ sound.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Interesting. That might be a possibility. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is a more detailed version of my two comments on the question.

I do not know the origin of the notation エンターティナー, but let me give a few plausible origins.

#### Hypercorrection

First, I think that hypercorrection is a pretty plausible reason.  For example, what was written as フイルム is now also written as フィルム, reflecting the pronunciation of the original word in English better (or at least intending to do so).  If one does not know the pronunciation of “entertainer” in English, one may well think that what is written as エンターテイナー is probably more precisely written as エンターティナー, “analogously” to other words such as フィルム.

A cursory look at some of the search results for [["エンターティナー" 発音]](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%22+%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3&hl=en&ie=utf-8) on Google seems to give enough evidence that some people indeed pronounce “エンターティナー” with the ティ /ti/ sound.

#### Non-standard use of letter ぃ

Second, some people seem to use little ぃ in a non-standard way; namely, to denote a weak い sound instead of modifying the preceding vowel to /i/.  For example, there is a cake product called [かすてぃら](http://www.oohara.co.jp/kasutera.html).  If I am not mistaken, this product name is pronounced as かすていら with /i/ sound or かすてーら with long /e/ sound, never with /ti/ sound.  As an another example, some people write “へい” in the Edo dialect as “へぃ”: searching [["へぃお待ち"]](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E3%81%B8%E3%81%83%E3%81%8A%E5%BE%85%E3%81%A1%22) on Google shows 213 results (by checking until the last search-result page).  For those who employ this non-standard convention, エンターティナー is pronounced as エンターテイナー with weak イ, which reflects the pronunciation of the English word as well as (or possibly even better than) the usual notation エンターテイナー.